# Formatting Currency in Java with SQL query

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access, ucanaccess

so I'm attempting to format currency in a SQL query through Java. It kind of formats it, but for some reason it adds the word Currency to it.

Here's my query

```
  String queryString = "select Format(UnitPrice*Quantity, 'Currency') as [Gross Price], ";
```

The output looks like this:
Gross Price:
Currency101
Currency234
Currency336

Also, when you remove the single quotes from Currency, it just gives me this runtime error:

```
 net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: CURRENCY
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:528)
```

Also, it outputs the data to a dynamic table, so I can't use Locales etc.

Comment: Why do you believe `Currency` is a recognized keyword for `format()` function in ucanaccess? Doesn't look like it is: https://github.com/andrew-nguyen/ucanaccess/blob/master/src/main/java/net/ucanaccess/converters/Functions.java#L380

Comment: @Andreas Actually had no idea that existed. Thanks. Fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/andrew-nguyen/ucanaccess/blob/master/src/main/java/net/ucanaccess/converters/Functions.java#L380

Currency is not a valid format, use standard instead

Answer (score 0):

The "Currency" named format was inadvertently omitted from the UCanAccess implementation of the `Format` function in versions 4.0.4 and earlier. It has been implemented in the UCanAccess source and will be included in the next release of UCanAccess.